# Next.js 14 and external API

Tags: next.js, next.js14

This is a pretty theoretical / generic question. I have a FastAPI backend with jwt authentication and I want to use Next.js 14 as the frontend. As a user logs in via a server action, she gets validated and a cookie is set client-side.

My main concern are the server pages - I plan to perform listing and CRUD operations on the API and I am not sure if I need to "map" the FastAPI (external) API to Next.js API routes or if I should just use directly the FastAPI external endpoints in my server components.

I find it a bit redundant to map all the functionality from the original API to the Next.js API routes *and* I am having problems passing the cookie with the JWT token to the API routes when called from the server. Any suggestion is more than welcome.